# How can I connect an AWS lambda inside a VPC to connect to a cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

### current situation:

I'm developing an AWS lambda that would launch an EC2 instance through a cloud formation stack.
I've deployed it inside a VPC, and thus had created endpoints to give it access to ressources such as S3/DynamoDB. However I cannot find any endpoints for the cloud formation, and as a result my function gets stucked at:
`Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cloudformation.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443`

#### update 1

Here is the snippet of code I'm using to connect to cloudformation:

```
self.cfn = session.resource('cloudformation')
```

```
 stackdata = self.cfn.create_stack(
        StackName="STACK-{}".format(instance_name),
        DisableRollback=True,
        TemplateURL=constants.TEMPLATE_TYPE[instance_type],
        Parameters=params,
        Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND','CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM']  
        )
```

Please be noted that my code works just fine in a none-VPC setup (if I deploy my lambda outside of a VPC)

Could anyone help me try to figure out what I'm missing here?

Comment: you are creating VPC endpoints because your lambda is in a private subnet?  That seems like the right thing to do, can you show us the snippet of code that is trying to connect to cloudformation API?  I'm assuming you are using one of the SDKs?

Comment: Is there a specific reason your Lambda function needs to run in the VPC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JDD, I've added the snippet in my question!

Comment: Your VPC requires the endpoints not because it's a VPC, but because it doesn't have a NAT gateway provisioned.

Comment: I've also thought the same, and provided it with a NAT gateway (though only to one of the subnets). However it didn't change anything to my function. Is there any parameters I need to set in order for my function to reside in that specific subnet?

Comment: FYI the CloudFormation service is one of the AWS services that support PrivatelInk (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html)), so you can create a VPC Endpoint to CloudFormation, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Jarmod for your comment! Following your link I was able to make it work using: 
interface endpoint of cloudformation + security groups: 443 in-bound rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda function that is deployed to the VPC doesn't have access to the internet. That means that it's not able to access any of the AWS services endpoints unless you do one of two things:

1. create a VPC endpoint for that service
2. Add NAT Gateway so Lambda function can use it to access internet

You add NAT gateway to the public subnet.
After that, you need to edit route tables for private subnets to point to the NAT gateway. When you add a Lambda function to the VPC, you choose in which subnets it can be deployed. It's necessary to associate all of those subnets with the NAT gateway, so you're sure that the Lambda function will always have access to the NAT gateway.

If your Lambda function really needs to be in VPC (it needs access to some other resources inside of VPC), this is ok, but if it's not really necessary, I'd suggest you just move it outside of VPC (NAT gateway is $35/month + traffic).

You can see the details here as well: [AWS Knowledgebase](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: I see that's indeed quite costly...
Thank you for your reply, I will investigate my case a little bit more !!